# Draw an arc of X degrees around center point in paperjs?

Tags: javascript, math, paperjs

I am struggling with the way paperjs specifies Arcs.  I have no idea why there isn't something which is basically:

```
var myArc = new Arc(degrees (radians?), center, radius);
```

because I can't figure out the advantage of (from, through, to) as an Arc descriptor.

At any rate, can someone tell me how to draw an Arc of say:  30 degrees from a fixed center point at a fixed radius?  Let's say center point is:  (cx, cy) and radius is 200.

I don't care about orientation, since I can rotate it after the fact.

TIA.

Answer (score 6):

There doesn't seem to be a built in way to do that. It does have "Path.Arc(start, through, end);" which make much more sense in most cases.

However, with that you could just engineer a way:

```
function getCreateArcInfo(degrees,center,radius){
    return {
        from: {
            x:center.x + radius,
            y: center.y
        },
        through: {
            x: center.x + Math.cos(degrees/2) * radius,
            y: center.y + Math.sin(degrees/2) * radius
        },
        to: {
            x: center.x + Math.cos(degrees) * radius,
            y: center.y + Math.sin(degrees) * radius
        },
        strokeColor: 'black'
    }
}
var arcValues = getCreateArcInfo(4, {x:253,y:334}, 160)
var myArc = new Path.Arc(arcValues)
```

http://goo.gl/YDQQl3

Comment: Marking this as the answer because it's very clear and clean.  But, please explain how (start, through, end) makes more sense.  Because I seriously don't understand why I would conceptualize an Arc that way.  When I think arc, I think a fraction of a circle, so I think center, radius, degrees.  I'm not being sarcastic at all.  I had literally never encountered this idea before paperjs.

Comment: Hold up.  The Math seems to be incorrect here.  Looking at the code, it appears to be correct for 90 degrees, but nothing else.  In your example you are passing 4 for the degree value.  But the Arc looks to be around 200 degrees.  I tried passing in 180 for degrees, and it does NOT produce a half circle.

Comment: @MonkRocker, because an arc is a path that is usually a part of a shape that usually consists of several paths all starting where the previous path ended and in the end loop. At least in all, I believe, cases I've used arcs. Yeah, I'm a bit shaky on the math there, but you get the idea. And I think you can probably make a working solution using MBo's math in the function. We basically had the same idea.

Comment: Years late, I know. The value passed in is in radians, not degrees. So as @MoonRocker says, 4 will give around 200 degrees (229.183). For 90 degree use 1.5708

Answer (score 1):

Just calculate needed coordinates (pseudocode):

```
fromPoint = Point(Center.X + Radius * Math.Cos(StartAngleInRadians), Center.Y + Radius * Math.Sin(StartAngleInRadians))
throughPoint = Point(Center.X + Radius * Math.Cos(StartAngleInRadians + ArcAngle/2), Center.Y + Radius * Math.Sin(StartAngleInRadians + ArcAngle/2))
toPoint = Point(Center.X + Radius * Math.Cos(StartAngleInRadians + ArcAngle), Center.Y + Radius * Math.Sin(StartAngleInRadians + ArcAngle))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a modified version of previous answers, with code converted to javascript (`paper` is the currently active [`PaperScope`](http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscope/)).

```js
let radius = 50
let rotation = 40 // applied rotation, in degrees for paperjs method
let len = 1.5 * Math.PI // 3-quarter circle arc length, radians

let arc = new paper.Path.Arc({
    from: [radius, 0],
    through: [radius * Math.cos(len/2), radius * Math.sin(len/2)],
    to: [radius * Math.cos(len), radius * Math.sin(len)],
    strokeWidth: 2,
    strokeColor: '#000'
})
arc.rotate(rotation)
```